# Automatically Create Windows Partitions Through Linux

Tags: windows, linux, partitioning

How to automatically create windows partitions(fat/ntfs) through Linux. I have all the required information for partitions to be created.

For example:

1. Size
2. Flag
3. Partition Type
4. etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use parted to do that. Something like:

```
parted /dev/sda mkpartfs <partition-type> <filesystem-type> <start> <end>
```

See parted's manpage for details.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/), which is a nice graphical partition editor. (depends on what you mean by "automatically"?)